# Inserting a new sheet alphabetically between two specific sheets

Tags: excel, vba

So far, I have created a button "AddaSheet" which pops up a userform where a name "NewSheetName" can be inserted in a text box. Then I have a button ("AddNow") which when clicked, needs to (and this is where I need help) do the following:

copy the "Template" sheet and rename it as "NewSheetName" (so the inputted text) and insert this new sheet alphabetically between two defined sheets.

I have many sheets in my workbook with different elements such as tables and so on, and I have grouped a particular kind of data set sheets together. As such, Ideally, if the new sheet can be inputted between a set range, it would be great.

Thank you in advance for your help!

p.s. I am a beginner, I would really appreciate if you could explain with comments what the code is doing.

Comment: Look at the `before` and `after` arguments in `worksheets.add`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to insert the new sheet alphabetically **between two defined sheets**. For example between a sheet called `Start` and a sheet called `End` then use the following code.

The advantage of this code is that there can be a alphabetically random order of sheets before `Start` and after `End` but only the new template sheet gets sorted in the correct way.

Example:
In the following sheets the new `Delta` sheet will be sorted in between `Beta` and `Epsilon` but the rest of the order is completely random:

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyAndSortSheetInBetween()
    Dim wsTemplate As Worksheet 'template sheet
    Set wsTemplate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template")

    Dim iStart As Long 'define your start sheet
    iStart = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Start").Index + 1

    Dim iEnd As Long 'define your end sheet
    iEnd = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stop").Index - 1

    If iEnd < iStart Then
        MsgBox "Stop sheet is before start sheet"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim NewName As String 'name that your new sheet will be
    NewName = "Delta"

    'find out which position is between "Start" and "Stop" sheet is the correct
    Dim i As Long
    For i = iStart To iEnd
        If UCase(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name) > UCase(NewName) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    'now i is the destination sheet number for your copied template sheet
    'and you can copy and rename your template
    wsTemplate.Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name = NewName
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the extra step I was missing!

Comment: I am having some trouble adding new sheet names where the new name comes after stop alphabetically (e.g. "Taa"). Any suggestion how I can change this? Thanks!

Comment: Also I am using excel 2016 in case it is relevant

Comment: @AniABC My bad missed a `- 1` in `iEnd = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stop").Index - 1` fixed the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This will sort your sheets into alphabetical order

```
Sub SortSheetsTabName()
    ' Turn off screenupdating so no visual effects to enduser
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim iSheets%, i%, j%
    ' Get number of sheets in workbook
    iSheets = Sheets.Count
    ' Loop through all sheets in workbook
    For i = 1 To iSheets - 1
        ' Loop through sheets to find correct position of worksheet
        For j = i + 1 To iSheets
            ' Test position
            If Sheets(j).Name < Sheets(i).Name Then
                ' Move sheet to alphabetical position
                Sheets(j).Move before:=Sheets(i)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    ' Turn on screenupdating for end user
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/workbooks-and-worksheets/sort-worksheets-alphanumerically-by-name)

Comment: Dear Tom, thank you for your quick response. Could you please help me understand what the following does? % symbol next to the isheets, what the i = 1 and -1 does and what i and j represent? Thank you very much, your help is really appreciated! Ani

Comment: The code will loop through all of your sheets and sort them into an alphabetical order. If your sheets are already alphabetised you could modify this to only work on the newly created sheet

Comment: @SolarMike yeah agreed

Comment: @Tom, plus 1'cos it is useful code -can be a base for lots of things.